# I am trying to make a list in a while loop but my loop will not restart

Tags: python

```
inp = input("Would you want to (A)dd or (D)elete something from the list? (E to exit) ")
mylist = []
while inp != "E":
    if inp == "A":
        add = input("Enter an item to add: ")
        mylist.append(add)
    elif inp == "D":
        delete = input("Enter an item to delete: ")
        mylist.remove(delete)`
```

When I do this, my program continues to ask for an item to add. How do I get my loop to start over?

Comment: The loop does start over, that's why it keeps asking you for an item to add.

Comment: I see your `inp` variable is not modified inside loop, so how do you think you would get out of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `inp` variable which is input under the while loop.

```
inp = ""

mylist = []
while inp != "E":
    inp = input("Would you want to (A)dd or (D)elete something from the list? (E to exit) ")
    if inp == "A":
        add = input("Enter an item to add: ")
        mylist.append(add)
    elif inp == "D":
        delete = input("Enter an item to delete: ")
        mylist.remove(delete)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the first `input()` within the `while` loop:

```
  while inp != "E":
      inp = input("Would you want to (A)dd or (D)elete something from the list? (E to exit) ")
```